# user with id:{0} does not exist,

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a learning management system which used WebAPI and IntegrationApI Provider project. when the solution is being run the following error arises
[image: Screen shot]
This is the exception that arises. I can't understand this exception niether can't find a solution over the internet. Please help

CODE:
namespace IntegrationAPIProviders
{
    public class TestIntegrationAPIProvider2 : IPlatform
    {

```
    public ID2LAppContext valenceAppContext { get; set; }
    public HostSpec valenceHost { get; set; }
    public ID2LUserContext valenceUserContext { get; set; }
    public ID2LUserContext valenceAdminContext { get; set; }

    private int _CurrentUserId;
    public int GetCurrentUserId()
    {
        if (_CurrentUserId == 0)
        {
            var allUsers = UserRepository.GetAllUsers();

            if (allUsers != null && allUsers.Count>0)
                _CurrentUserId = allUsers.First().UserId;
            else
                _CurrentUserId = 1;
        }

        return _CurrentUserId;
    }

    public void SetCurrentUserId(int userId)

    {
        _CurrentUserId = userId;
    }

    public PlatformUser GetUserName(int userId)
    {
        var user = UserRepository.GetUserById(userId);
        if (user == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("user with id:{0} does not exist, please add the user first", userId));

        return new PlatformUser() { UserName = user.Name, Id = userId };

        // create a proxy object of web service 
        // invoke that web serice
        // rteurn value

        // coonect to db
        // execute the sql
        // rteurn the result

        //return AllUsersList.Single(x => x.Id == userId);

        //return new PlatformUser() { Id = userId, FirstName = "Student", LastName = "0", ExternalEmail = "bsuser1@brightscribe.com" };
    }

    public List<PlatformUser> GetUserIdsForCourse(int courseId)
    {
        var users = UserRepository.GetAllUsersByCourseId(courseId);

        return users.Select(x => new PlatformUser() { Id = x.UserId, FirstName = x.Name, UserName = x.Name }).ToList();

        //var userList = AllUsersList.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(courseId.ToString())).ToList();
        //userList.AddRange(AllUsersList.Where(x => x.LastName.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
        //return userList;
    }

    List<PlatformUser> IPlatform.GetAllUsers(int courseId)
    {
        return AllUsersList;
    }

    public List<PlatformUser> AllUsersList
    {
        get
        {
            var users = UserRepository.GetAllUsers();
            return users.Select(x => new PlatformUser() { Id = x.UserId, FirstName = x.Name, UserName = x.Name }).ToList();

            //return new List<PlatformUser>()
            //{
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=0, FirstName = "Student 00", LastName = "1,2", ExternalEmail = "bsuser0@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=1, FirstName = "Student 01", LastName = "1,2,3", ExternalEmail = "bsuser1@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=2, FirstName = "Student 02", LastName = "2,3", ExternalEmail = "bsuser2@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=3, FirstName = "Student 03", LastName = "1,3", ExternalEmail = "bsuser3@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=4, FirstName = "Student 04", LastName = "3", ExternalEmail = "bsuser12@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=5, FirstName = "Student 05", LastName = "2", ExternalEmail = "bsuser13@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=6, FirstName = "Student 06", LastName = "1", ExternalEmail = "bsuser14@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=7, FirstName = "Student 07", LastName = "1,3", ExternalEmail = "bsuser15@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=8, FirstName = "Developer 08", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser4@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=9, FirstName = "Developer 09", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser5@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=10, FirstName = "Developer 10", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser6@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=11, FirstName = "Instructor 11", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser7@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=12, FirstName = "Instructor 12", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser8@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=13, FirstName = "Instructor 13", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser9@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=14, FirstName = "Admin 14", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser10@brightscribe.com" },
            //new PlatformUser() {Id=15, FirstName = "Manager 15", LastName = "ALL", ExternalEmail = "bsuser11@brightscribe.com" }
            //};
        }
    }

    public List<PlatformCourse> AllCourses
    {
        get
        {
            var courses = CourseManager.GetAllCourse();

            return courses.Select(x => new PlatformCourse() { Id = x.CourseId, CourseName = x.Name }).ToList();
            //return new List<PlatformCourse>()
            //{
            //    new PlatformCourse(){ Id = 1, CourseName = "Course1"},
            //    new PlatformCourse(){ Id = 2, CourseName = "Course2"},
            //    new PlatformCourse(){ Id = 3, CourseName = "Course3"},
            //};
        }
    }

    public List<PlatformCourse> GetCoursesForUser(int userId)
    {
        //TODO: need a filter so that only the courses for the users are obtained.
        var courses = CourseManager.GetAllCourse();
        return courses.Select(x => new PlatformCourse() { Id = x.CourseId, CourseName = x.Name }).ToList();

        //var user = AllUsersList.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Single();
        //if (user.LastName.StartsWith("ALL"))
        //    return this.AllCourses;

        //List<string> courseIds = user.LastName.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        //List<PlatformCourse> userCourseList = new List<PlatformCourse>();
        //foreach (var requiredCourseId in courseIds)
        //{
        //    userCourseList.Add(AllCourses.Where(x => x.Id.ToString().Equals(requiredCourseId)).Single());
        //}

        //return userCourseList;
    }

    public PlatformUserRole GetUserRole(int courseId, int userId)
    {
        //UserEnrollment userEnrolled = UserRepository.GetUserEnrollmentById(userId, courseId);
        //return (userEnrolled == null) ? PlatformUserRole.None : (PlatformUserRole)userEnrolled.UserRole;


        var user = UserRepository.GetUserById(userId);
        if (user == null)
            return PlatformUserRole.Admin;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Phone))
        {
            if (user.Phone.Contains("StudentServices"))
                return PlatformUserRole.StudentServices;

            if (user.Phone.Contains("Student"))
                return PlatformUserRole.Student;

            if (user.Phone.Contains("Developer"))
                return PlatformUserRole.Developer;

            if (user.Phone.Contains("Instructor"))
                return PlatformUserRole.Instructor;

            if (user.Phone.Contains("Manager"))
                return PlatformUserRole.Manager;

            if (user.Phone.Contains("Admin"))
                return PlatformUserRole.Admin;

            if (user.Phone.Contains("Employer"))
                return PlatformUserRole.Employer;
        }

        if (user.Name.Contains("StudentServices"))
            return PlatformUserRole.StudentServices;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Student"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Student;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Admin"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Admin;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Applicant"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Applicant;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Developer"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Developer;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Employer"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Employer;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Instructor"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Instructor;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Manager"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Manager;

        else if (user.Name.Contains("Instructor"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Instructor;
        else if (user.Name.Contains("Instructor"))
            return PlatformUserRole.Instructor;
        else
        {
            return PlatformUserRole.Admin;
        }

        //switch (userId)
        //{
        //    case 0:
        //    case 1:
        //    case 2:
        //    case 3:
        //    case 4:
        //    case 5:
        //    case 6:
        //    case 7:
        //        role = PlatformUserRole.Student;
        //        break;
        //    case 8:
        //    case 9:
        //    case 10:
        //        role = PlatformUserRole.Developer;
        //        break;
        //    case 11:
        //    case 12:
        //    case 13:
        //        role = PlatformUserRole.Instructor;
        //        break;
        //    case 14:
        //        role = PlatformUserRole.Admin;
        //        break;
        //    case 15:
        //        role = PlatformUserRole.Manager;
        //        break;
        //    default:
        //        break;
        //}
        //return role;
    }

    public bool UpdateGradeData(int courseId, int userId, decimal grade, int d2lGradeId)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("UpdateGradeData invoked for , UserId:{0}, Grade:{1}, d2l:{2}", userId, grade, d2lGradeId));
        return true;
    }

    public List<PlatformTrigger> GetTriggers(int courseId)
    {
        return new List<PlatformTrigger>()
        {
            new PlatformTrigger(){ Id=0, ModuleId="TriggerModule0"},
            new PlatformTrigger(){ Id=1, ModuleId="TriggerModule1"},
            new PlatformTrigger(){ Id=2, ModuleId="TriggerModule2"},
            new PlatformTrigger(){ Id=3, ModuleId="TriggerModule3"},
            new PlatformTrigger(){ Id=4, ModuleId="TriggerModule4"},
            new PlatformTrigger(){ Id=5, ModuleId="TriggerModule5"}
        };
    }


    public bool CheckTriggers(int courseId, int userid, int d2LTriggerId)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public List<PlatformUser> GetAllInstructors(int courseId)
    {
        var courseUsers = GetUserIdsForCourse(courseId);
        return courseUsers.Where(x => GetUserRole(courseId, x.Id) == PlatformUserRole.Instructor).ToList();
        //List<PlatformUser> alUsers = PlatformFactory.CreateProvider().GetUserIdsForCourse(courseId);
        //List<PlatformUser> instructorsList = new List<PlatformUser>();
        //foreach (var user in alUsers)
        //{
        //    PlatformUserRole userRole = PlatformFactory.CreateProvider().GetUserRole(courseId, user.Id);
        //    if (userRole == PlatformUserRole.Instructor)
        //        instructorsList.Add(user);
        //}

        //return instructorsList;
    }

    public bool TranscriptionsCompleted(int courseId, int userId, int d2lNextChapterId)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("TranscriptionsCompleted invoked for , CourseId:{0}, UserId:{1}, d2lNextChapterId:{2}", courseId, userId, d2lNextChapterId));
        return true;
    }

    public bool TranscriptionsIncomplete(int courseId, int userId, int d2LNextChapterId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("only available in brightspace API");
    }

    public EnrollmentData API_GetUserEnrollmentById(int userId, int orgUnitId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("only available in brightspace API");
    }

    public List<TestDetail> GetTestCompletionDates(int courseId, int userId)
    {
        return new List<TestDetail>()
        {
            new TestDetail(){ Grade = 1.1m, GradeWeight = 1.11m, TestId = 1, TestName = "Test1", TestPassed = false },
            new TestDetail(){ Grade = 2.2m, GradeWeight = 2.22m, TestId = 2, TestName = "Test2", TestPassed = false}
        };
    }

    public GradeValue GetGradeValue(int courseId, int userId, int gradeId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("only available in brightspace API");
    }


    public List<DropboxFolder> GetDropboxFolders(int courseId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("only available in brightspace API");
    }

    public List<EntityDropbox> GetDropboxFolderSubmissions(int courseId, int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("only available in brightspace API");
    }

    public GradeValue GetFinalGradeValue(int courseId, int userId, int gradeId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("only available in brightspace API");
    }

    public MemoryStream GetDropboxFolderSubmissionFile(int courseId, int folderId, int submissionId, int fileId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("only available in brightspace API");
    }


}
```

}

Comment: it's simple, you have and userId but you don't have an data about that user so in `var user` it returns null and this exception occurred.

Comment: userRepository.GetUserbyId() method is retirning null.Kindly post the code of  GetUserbyId method.Also you need to check which sp/table the method is calling and does the dB table has entry of records.

Comment: You can't understand the exception that _you yourself_ are throwing in response to no user being returned? Looking at your code, I'm going to go ahead and assume that that user doesn't exist, which is also what you have coded your error message to say.

Comment: public int GetCurrentUserId()
        {
            if (_CurrentUserId == 0)
            {
                var allUsers = UserRepository.GetAllUsers();

                if (allUsers != null && allUsers.Count>0)
                    _CurrentUserId = allUsers.First().UserId;
                else
                    _CurrentUserId = 1;
            }

            return _CurrentUserId;
        }
 here is the code

Comment: a) You're not calling `GetCurrentUserId()` in your code. We need to see the `GetUserById` method. b) Please put that in your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your image does the following:

- Call to the method `UserRepository.GetUserById` with a given `userId`
- Check if that call returned a result
- If it didn't return a result throw an error which tells you that the user with that given id doesn't exist

Since you are the developer I shouldn't need to explain that to you ;-)

To solve the problem check the content of `userId` and check your data source for the existence of that id